# How to calculate the following expectation and variance?

Tags: calculus, integration, expected-value, maple, mathematica

Given
$$X_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2),$$
$$X_2 \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2),$$
$$X_1 \mathrm{\ and\ } X_2 \mathrm{\ are\ independent}.$$
and
$$Y = \max(\max(X_1,0) + X_2, 0),$$
find
$$E(Y) \mathrm{\ \ and\ \ } Var(Y).$$
Python expression is preferred.

---

I tried using [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/) to calculate the expectation and convert the solution to Python but the solution is wrong and not runnable in Python. Here is the Maple script:

```
with(CodeGeneration):
p1 := 1/(sqrt(2pi)s1) exp(-(x1-m1)^2 / (2s1^2));
p2 := 1/(sqrt(2pi)s2) exp(-(x2-m2)^2 / (2s2^2));

y1 := piecewise(x1<=0, 0, x1>0, x1);
y2 := y1 + x2;
y3 := piecewise(y2<=0, 0, y2>0, y2);
y3_int := y3 * p1 * p2;

F := int(y3_int, [x1=-infinity..infinity, x2=-infinity..infinity]);
F := optimize(F)
Python(F);
```

Here is the result:

```
cg = 0.1e1 / pi / s1 / s2 * sympy.integrate(math.exp(-(x2 - m2) ** 2 / s2 ** 2 / 2) * sympy.integrate(0 if 0 if x1 <= 0 else x1 if 0 < x1 else 0 + x2 <= 0 else 0 if x1 <= 0 else x1 if 0 < x1 else 0 + x2 if 0 < 0 if x1 <= 0 else x1 if 0 < x1 else 0 + x2 else 0 * math.exp(-(x1 - m1) ** 2 / s1 ** 2 / 2), x1 == xrange(-infinity,infinity)), x2 == xrange(-infinity,infinity)) / 2
```

---

I also tried using [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to calculate the expectation with the following script. However, it is very slow. It has run for 3 hours but no result is returned.

```
import math
import sympy as sp


m1 = sp.Symbol('m1')
s1 = sp.Symbol('s1')
m2 = sp.Symbol('m2')
s2 = sp.Symbol('s2')

x1 = sp.Symbol('x1')
x2 = sp.Symbol('x2')

p1 = 1 / (sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi) * s1) * sp.exp(-(x1-m1)**2 / (2 * s1**2))
p2 = 1 / (sp.sqrt(2 * sp.pi) * s2) * sp.exp(-(x2-m2)**2 / (2 * s2**2))

y1 = sp.Piecewise((0, x1 <= 0), (x1, True))
y2 = y1 + x2
y3 = sp.Piecewise((0, y2 <= 0), (y2, True))
y3_int = y3 * p1 * p2

expe = sp.integrate(y3_int, (x1, -sp.oo, sp.oo), (x2, -sp.oo, sp.oo))
```

---

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you are assuming independence of $X_1,X_2$ which is not given.  Indeed, without knowing the joint distribution you can't say much about $\mathbb{E}Y$ or $\operatorname{Var}Y$.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's as far as I could get. To simplify things let $f_1$ and $f_2$ denote the probability density functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Let $X$ denote a random variable with the normal distribution $N(0,1)$.
$$E(Y)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-x_1}^{\infty}(x_1+x_2)f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\:dx_2dx_1 + \int_{-\infty}^0\int_0^{\infty}x_2f_2(x_2)\:dx_2f_1(x_1)dx_1$$
because there are two cases where $Y$ is not $0$.

$1)$ $X_1 > 0$ and $X_2 > -X_1$

$2)$ $X_1\leq 0$ but $X_2 > 0$

The second term simplifies to
$$ P(X_1\leq 0)\int_0^{\infty}x_2f_2(x_2)\:dx_2=P(X_1\leq 0)\Big[\int_{-\mu_2/\sigma_1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x_2e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_2^2}dx_2+\mu_2P(X\geq \frac{-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})\Big]$$
$$P(X_1\leq 0)\Big[\frac{\sigma_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_2^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}+\mu_2P(X\geq \frac{-\mu_2}{\sigma_2})\Big]$$

The first term simplifies to
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}(x_1+x_2)f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\:dx_1dx_2+
\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-x_1}^{0}(x_1+x_2)f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\:dx_2dx_1$$
the first term of which simplifies to
$$P(X_2\geq 0)\Big[\frac{\sigma_1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_1^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}+\mu_1P(X\geq \frac{-\mu_1}{\sigma_1})\Big]+P(X_1\geq 0)\Big[\frac{\sigma_2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_2^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}+\mu_2P(X\geq \frac{-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\Big]$$
For given means and variances the probabilities would not be hard to find using a computer and $z$-scores. As for the remaining term, I think it's possible to simplify it, but I haven't tried since the work required to do so is enormous.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your method. For the remaining part, I used numerical method. Instead of using pure numerical integral, this mixed solution already improves speed by 10x.

For the remaining part, can you provide some hints if possible? Thanks again!

Comment: Forgot some factors from $u$-subs. Fixed now. To proceed with the last term, use $u$-subs, distribute the integral signs across terms, and make sure the integration order is correct for each term. E.g. integrate over $dx_1$ first for $\sigma_1x_1e^{-\frac{1}{2}x_1^2}$.

Comment: You'll get stuck at the terms with the $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. There is no way to simplify these terms. They require you to determine the area under the curve of $N_{X_1,X_2}$, the bivariate normal distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ for a very specific wedge. I don't know how to estimate this with a computer.

Comment: If there is no much simplification for the remaining part, I think the problem is basically solved now. Using numerical integral method for this part instead of the original function already saves a lot of time. It seems integrate over [[-inf, inf], [-inf, inf]] consumes much more time than [[-inf, inf], [-delta, 0]]. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Ryan. I calculated several times and found the second term of $E(Y)$ is $P(X_1\leq 0)\Big[\sigma_2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\mu_2^2}{2\sigma_2^2}}+\mu_2P(X_2\geq 0)\Big]$. Can you please check your result?

Comment: My bad, should be correct now. Mine differs from yours because I don't think you changed the bounds properly on the first $u$-substitution.